Putting text inside an image with latex code
In the new book I translate in Greek, the first page in each chapter has the form shown in the attached image. Is there a way to reproduce this page in XeLaTEX? I saved the page in pdf format and then I removed the text inside, in order to type this text in WinEdt and not to insert it as an image in Adobe Illustrator. My idea was to use a minipage that fills the gap between the left and the right column, and then to put this minipage in the appropriate position via hspace and vspace, but this does not work. Any idea? Thanks a lot, Athanasios

you can add the image in a shipout/background hook.
